# XPath to match elements with missing/unspecified attributes?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

How do I use XPath to only match the first two `li` tags, where the `class` is unspecified? I tried `//li[@class='']` as well as `//li[@class=nil]` but that didn't return any results.

```
<li>STUFF</li>
<li>MORE STUFF</li>
<li class='whatever'>DO NOT MATCH ME</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//li[not(@class)]
```

will match all `li` elements that do not have a `@class` attribute.